# TempInsertStateItemShort procedure on ASPState is taking more than 1 second to execute

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session, database-performance, aspstate

I'm working on a .NET website who runs in load balance within more than one server and because of that I need to have my session on SQL Server.

In the last 2 weeks I've notice that the procedure **TempInsertStateItemShort** is taking more than 1 second to run.

does anyone had experience that? How can I improve performance on ASPState database?

Here some extra information
- currently there is about 10k users on site
- about 1k users simultaneous
- ASPState database has size of 3mb only (we don't use much Session, only for few things)

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: If memory serves, the TempInsertStateItemShort SPROC indicates that your session is less than 7,000 bytes in size; otherwise it would be using the TempInsertStateItemLong. I think you need help on profiling/optimizing the SPROC involved and I suggest you post this question to [DBA StackExchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks Karl, I will post this question there.

Comment: for the record: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45172/tempinsertstateitemshort-procedure-on-aspstate-is-taking-more-than-1-second-to-e